# SQL*Plus script executed twice

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ksh

I'm trying to run a script using sqlplus. My script is a simple delete statement. I execute it by putting the following in my ksh terminal:

```
sqlplus username/'password' @../sql/delete_societes.sql
```

../sql/delete_societes.sql is

```
DELETE FROM f2020.SOCIETES;
/
```

For some reason, it runs twice, causing the output "0 lines deteleted" to be printed twice and causing errors when I try to do an insert instead of a delete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make your script do either;

```
DELETE FROM f2020.SOCIETES
/
```

**or**

```
DELETE FROM f2020.SOCIETES;
```

without the slash.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/slash.html#GUID-F5EEC10C-6E74-4CCE-A196-C591F83C3D44):

> /(slash)
>
> Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which is stored in the SQL buffer.

and in the example further down:

> Enter a slash (/) to re-execute the command in the buffer

... which is exactly what you are seeing.

[Elsewhere in those docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-19D38608-829E-49BC-A452-50895163E311):

> The semicolon (;) means that this is the end of the command. Press Return or click Execute. SQL*Plus processes the command and displays the results

Like many clients SQL*Plus treats the semicolon at the end of your SQL statement as a statement separator - it is *not* part of the statement itself (which causes some confusion for e.g. dynamic SQL and JDBC calls) - and when it sees it it executes the command. The executed statement stays in the command buffer; and if you `list` to see the current command buffer, it will not show that semicolon.  When you issue a slash it executes the buffer again.

---

Things are slightly different for PL/SQL; there the PL/SQL block has to be terminated with a semicolon, which *is* part of the block, and appears in the buffer. You have to use a slash to [execute a PL/SQL block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SQL-Plus-basics.html#GUID-1C95D0FD-41A2-487A-A1F0-10509B8FC62C).

Comment: Which then begs the question: why *doesn't* SQL Developer do this? (I found this question when confused why a script that worked fine in SQL Developer failed in SQL*Plus.)

Comment: @MarkRaymond - good question, and oddly I thought it did. I imagine it's because it doesn't have the same concept of a command buffer that SQL\*Plus has. There the slash runs whatever is in the buffer, implicitly terminating the current input if that's active; if you've already terminated (and executed) the statement with a semicolon, or just ended the input with a blank line (depending on sqlblanklines setting) then it *just* re-executes the buffer. That doesn't map to how SQL Developer works though. It doesn't make much sense when running SQL\*Plus non-interacitvely either, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

An example where you can see the sqlplus buffer content for SQL and PLSQL.

```
me@XEPDB1> help run

 RUN
 ---

 Lists and executes the most recently executed SQL command or
 PL/SQL block which is stored in the SQL buffer. The buffer has
 no command history list and does not record SQL*Plus commands.

 R[UN]


me@XEPDB1> help /

 / (slash)
 ---------

 Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block
 which is stored in the SQL buffer. Use slash (/) at the command
 prompt or line number prompt in SQL*Plus command line. The buffer
 has no command history and does not record SQL*Plus commands.

 /

me@XEPDB1> clear buffer                                                                                                                                           [1/651]
buffer cleared
me@XEPDB1> l
SP2-0223: No lines in SQL buffer.
me@XEPDB1> select * from dual
  2  /

D
-
X                          

me@XEPDB1> l
  1* select * from dual                 
me@XEPDB1> select * from dual;

D                    
-           
X

me@XEPDB1> l
  1* select * from dual
me@XEPDB1> /         

D                                       
-
X          

me@XEPDB1> r
  1* select * from dual

D
-
X

me@XEPDB1> begin null; end;
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

me@XEPDB1> l
  1* begin null; end;
me@XEPDB1> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

me@XEPDB1> r
  1* begin null; end;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```