# How to create the multiple tables in SQL developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I made a fully normalized ERD and I wrote the queries, but it did not create the tables. Please help me to fix what I wrote.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE SERVER (
       SERVER_ID        VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
       SERVER_IP        VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
       SERVER_LOCATION  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
       SERVER_BRAND     VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT SERVER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( SERVER_ID )
);
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION (
       APP_ID       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       ACCOUNT_NUM  INT NOT NULL,
       RECORD_ID    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
       VERSION_ID   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
       LAST_UPDATE  DATE NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_PK PRIMARY KEY ( APP_ID ),
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY ( ACCOUNT_NUM )
              REFERENCES ACCOUNT ( ACCOUNT_NUM ),
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY ( RECORD_ID )
              REFERENCES RECORD ( RECORD_ID )
);
CREATE TABLE RECORD (
       RECORD_ID  VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       VIN_NUM    VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       SERVER_ID  VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT RECORD_PK PRIMARY KEY ( RECORD_ID ),
       CONSTRAINT RECORD_FK1 FOREIGN KEY ( VIN_NUM )
              REFERENCES VEHICLE ( VIN_NUM ),
       CONSTRAINT RECORD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY ( SERVER_ID )
              REFERENCES SERVER2 ( SERVER_ID )
);
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE (
       VIN_NUM    VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       V_MILEAGE  NUMBER
(,0) NOT NULL , V_GASUSED VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL , V_ELECTRICALMILES NUMBER(,0) NOT NULL , DRIVER_ID VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL , CONSTRAINT VEHICLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (VIN_NUM), CONSTRAINT VEHICLE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DRIVER_ID) REFERENCES DRIVER (DRIVER_ID) );

CREATE TABLE SO_MODEL.DRIVER (
       DRIVER_ID         VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       LICENSE_NUM       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       LAST_NAME         VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL,
       INSURANCE_POLICY  VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       ACCOUNT_NUM       NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT DRIVER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( DRIVER_ID ),
       CONSTRAINT DRIVER_FK1 FOREIGN KEY ( ACCOUNT_NUM )
              REFERENCES ACCOUNT ( ACCOUNT_NUM )
);
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
       ACCOUNT_NUM     NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL,
       DRIVER_ID       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       DEVICE_ID       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       DATE_CREATED    DATE NOT NULL,
       ACCOUNT_STATUS  VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT ACCOUNT_PK PRIMARY KEY ( ACCOUNT_NUM ),
       CONSTRAINT ACCOUNT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY ( DRIVER_ID )
              REFERENCES DRIVER ( DRIVER_ID )
);
```

Comment: Didn't I answer that, already, here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60996247/which-statement-is-needed-to-revise

Comment: So you did @littlefoot, weird...

Answer (score 0):

You have circular references.

You're trying to create tables with Foreign Key constraints to other tables which do not yet exist.

Your second create table -

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION (
       APP_ID       VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       ACCOUNT_NUM  INT NOT NULL,
       RECORD_ID    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
       VERSION_ID   VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
       LAST_UPDATE  DATE NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_PK PRIMARY KEY ( APP_ID ),
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY ( ACCOUNT_NUM )
              REFERENCES ACCOUNT ( ACCOUNT_NUM ),
       CONSTRAINT APPLICATION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY ( RECORD_ID )
              REFERENCES RECORD ( RECORD_ID )
);
```

To create this table you need to already have ACCOUNT and RECORD tables created.

The easiest way around this is to create your tables without the foreign key constraints, then after they all exist, then run a series of ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT calls to add the FK rules back.

Something like...

```
alter table application add constraint application_fk1 foreign key(account_num) references account(account_num);
```

When you say you're tables weren't created - you haven't shared with us how you attempted to create them in the first place, or share any error messages encountered when you tried.

If you were using Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler to build this, we make it easy to generate the DDL with the FKs as ALTERS at the end to avoid this problem in the first place.

Finally, you have syntax issues with your VEHICLE table

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLE (
       VIN_NUM    VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
       V_MILEAGE  NUMBER(,0) NOT NULL ,
       V_GASUSED VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ,
       V_ELECTRICALMILES NUMBER(,0) NOT NULL ,
       DRIVER_ID VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT VEHICLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (VIN_NUM), CONSTRAINT VEHICLE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DRIVER_ID) REFERENCES DRIVER (DRIVER_ID) );
```

The 2 NUMBER columns are defined as NUMBER(,0) - that's not valid. I noticed it quite easily when I pasted your code into SQL Developer, the parser throws up an indicator that it's bad AND the formatter will stop formatting code when it gets to that point.

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to make the multiple tables without alter table statement?